# Change iframe height on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I tried [Change height of an iframe on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416696/change-height-of-an-iframe-on-hover) and I want to change height of iframe from iframe. Parent site javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function changeiFrameHeight(){
      $(".iframesvaold").hover(function(){
       $('#svaiFrame').height(600);
      });         
    };
    </script>
```

And call from iframe:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  parent.changeiFrameHeight();
 });
 </script>
```

It doesn´t work. What I am doing wrong?

Sorry for my English. Thank you!

//On same domain

Comment: It sounds like your trying to change an iframe to be the height of its cross-domain'd source. This is not possible, for security reasons (and very annoying). Look up 'cross-domain iframe communication' for workarounds, although they required code on both servers.

Comment: No I want to change height on same domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If understand correctly, you are trying to resize an iFrame present on the page. Try something like below

```
  window.parent.document.getElementById("svaiFrame").height = 600;
```

Comment: Thanks but ... it doesn´t work. If this help ... Firebug: Permission denied to access property 'document'

Comment: try setting document.domain to the same value in both the iframe and the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, have you tried::

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function changeiFrameHeight(){
    $(".iframesvaold").hover(function(){
        $('#svaiFrame').css("height", "600px");
    });         
  }
</script>
```